# Changing the background color of an element sets websites text to the color

Tags: javascript, html, css, bookmarks

Im trying to make a javascript bookmark using [The code I wrote](https://codepen.io/xderpyxcreeperx/pen/QWjBWyO). It's supposed to add an element (in this case it adds a div. The div is as large as the size of innerHeight and innerWidth. The height shrinks by a few pixels every 250 milliseconds. It works on CodePen, but when I try it on another website, it changes the entire HTML of the page to "white" (which is the background color of the added element). Here is the code:

```
var falseLoaderContainer = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
falseLoaderContainer.innerHTML += `<div id="falseLoader"></div>`;
var falseLoader = document.getElementById("falseLoader");
falseLoader.style.position = `absolute`;
falseLoader.style.width = `${window.innerWidth}px`;
falseLoader.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;
falseLoader.style.bottom = `0px`;
falseLoader.style.left = `0px`;
falseLoader.style.backgroundColor = `white`;
var falseLoaderHeight = falseLoader.style.height.replace(/px/g, "");
var updateFalseLoader = setInterval(function () {
    falseLoaderHeight *= 1;
    falseLoaderHeight -= Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
    falseLoader.style.height = falseLoaderHeight + "px";
    if (falseLoaderHeight <= 0) {
        clearInterval(updateFalseLoader);
    }
}, 250);
```

Comment: everywhere I tried it worked fine, but if you want you can try replacing the style with which you cange the css property form `element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';` to `element.style = "background-color: COLOR;");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");
element.setAttribute("style", "background-color: COLOR;");
```

or:

```
var element = document.getElementBYId("id");
element.style = "background-color: COLOR;");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, after a bit of tinkering i managed to get it working. But in reply to your first suggestion, I recommend you take a look at [This](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)